# Indent unnumbered chapter in TOC with multitoc (in presence of tocstyle)

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script, tocstyle, multitoc

I'm having a problem mixing `multitoc` with `tocstyle`. What I want is my unnumbered chapters in the TOC to be indented (in this case `\addchap{Introduction}`).

I figured out that `\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}` will give me the indentation that I want, but it changes the font and formatting. The best solution will be to get the desired indentation *without* using `tocstyle`, i.e., achieve my desired indentation only within the confines of `\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}`.

**MWE:**

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

%\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle} % this works but changes the formatting

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter A}
\chapter{Chapter B}

\end{document}
```

Desired indentation of "Introduction" but not the font/formatting that I want:
[image]

Desired font/formatting but without the indentation of "Introduction" that I desire:
[image]

Comment: The usage of `multitoc` is not recommended. There is a suggestion without this package in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Note that it is not recommended to use package `multitoc`. It is outdated and seems to be not maintained anymore. Markus Kohm has warned me that the usage of `multitoc` results in empty other lists (LOF, LOT and new defined lists).

Here is a suggestion that directly uses the `multicol` package for the TOC with two columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt,toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage{multicol}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter A}
\chapter{Chapter B}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Original answer**

Use KOMA-option `toc=indentunnumbered`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Chapter A}
\chapter{Chapter B}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update to put me on a better TOC path.